# How can I change the background colour of a web part page without Sharepoint Designer?

Tags: 2010, web-part-page

Does anybody know how can I change the background colour of a web part page without Sharepoint Designer? I am restricted with what I can do so can't use Designer or change the Master Template.

I just want to change the whole background of the page to a different colour (and leave the web parts with a white background). I have searched around but can't seem to find anything.

Any help is gratefully received!!

Thanks, 
Dub

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it can be done with css with header and table changing:

```
.s4-wpTopTable {
background: 
#FEE;
}

.ms-WPHeader {
background: 
#FEE;
}
```

If you want to apply this to particular web-part, you can add additional css-marker class on you web-part render methods to find you web part instance later or use js/jQuery-client bases techniques to apply/change css on target webpart.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried this by adding it to a Content Editor Web Part (in a Style tag) but it only seems to change the colour of the header of the Web Parts, the bits in between the web part are still white :S 

I wanted to change the main background to a colour, is this possible or am I putting the code in the wrong place?